# Filtros de imagenes con hilos en java

Tags: java, imagen, hilos

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con hilos en Java, necesito hacer en consola un menú que cambie el filtro de una imagen utilizando hilos. Sé como hacer los filtros pero no he comprendido como usar los hilos.

Comment: https://jarroba.com/multitarea-e-hilos-en-java-con-ejemplos-thread-runnable/

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base al documento [ask] para que obtengas la ayuda requerida en el sitio, te sugerimos editar tu pregunta, agrega tu código. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos!